# Centered dialog on Facebook canvas app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

How can I create a dialog that stays centered as the user scrolls through my Facebook canvas app?

I've read [this](http://blog.sjhewitt.co.uk/2011/05/positioning-dialogs-in-facebook-canvas-applications/) post on the subject, but the method described there (listening to the undocumented facebook-event) did not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried just using CSS position:fixed?

Comment: Well, you could always try to replace listening to the undocumented event with a simple interval in which you check the scroll position permanently and adapt your dialogs position to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Facebook no longer poll the server to update the pageInfo as part of their library. However, it's fairly simple to write something that polls it yourself, and move the dialog appropriately:

```
var timeout;
var positionDialog = function(){
    FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(pageInfo){
         $("#dialog").animate({top: Math.max(parseInt(pageInfo.scrollTop) - parseInt(pageInfo.offsetTop) + 
            ((parseInt(pageInfo.clientHeight)-$("#dialog").outerHeight())/2), 0)}, 100);
         timeout = setTimeout(positionDialog, 250);
    });
};

var showDialog = function(){
    // show your dialog
    $("#dialog").show();
    positionDialog();
};

var hideDialog = function(){
    $("#dialog").hide();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
};
```

Note: I've used setTimeout rather than setInterval, as you don't know how long the ajax calls will take, and don't want to be handling out of order responses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess this would work, but the dialog would only be centered at the same rate as the polling was done, correct?

Comment: yes, unfortunately due to cross domain restrictions, this is the only way to do it. It's impossible to access the window scroll position and iframe offset directly using JS from inside your app's iframe.