# position absolute within iframe - facebook canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, iframe

I am trying to `position:absolute` a element `mydiv` inside a `facebook canvas` page,  which is an `iframe`.
But it does not work since i would have to control `mydiv` from the parent page.

Is it possible to dynamically write into the top frame with javascript? 
i found this, but not sure how to implement it, especially this line `frames[name]`.

```
var iframe = top.frames[name].document;
var css = '' +
                     '<style type="text/css">' +
                     '#mydiv{margin:0;padding:0;postiton:absolute}' +
                     '</style>';
iframe.open();
iframe.write(css);
iframe.close();
```

**edit:** this helped out: [Centered dialog on Facebook canvas app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000073/centered-dialog-on-facebook-canvas-app)

Comment: You can't break out of your iframe but I don't understand why can't you position your content within the iFrame itself

Comment: @Igy im using http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html for popups and the position fixed, absolute does not respond inside FB's canvas app